# A question about Google Store listing screenshot sizes

Tags: android, google-console-developer

I have a question regarding the screenshots for devices on the Google Play listing that I place on my Google Console. I am using an app mockup tool that places a screenshot within a device frame and allows for writing text above or under the device.

It is mentioned on the site that they follow the Google Play console guidelines regarding maximum sizes. Though, that is not my question.

The end result of the mockup photos are ~1200 width / ~2200 height and the sizes vary between 0.5-2MB. I have put those images on one of my budget devices and it took the device around 4 seconds to display each image properly (it starts fuzzy and then clears over 4 seconds).

So, here is my questions. Does the Google Play console resize the mockup images or will it display those images as is resulting in the user having to wait for the images to clear. If the console does not resize the images, should I go ahead and resize the images myself to half of the original size?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play does do some server-side re-encoding of images, and also some reducing the size to be more friendly to particular devices. This isn't documented though and is subject to change at any time.

Comment: Yes, I have figured it out when I posted my app. Thanks, though. I am accepting your answer for future askers.